# Can you identify this plant just by its seed pods?

Tags: identification, flowers, seeds

What is the plant with these seed pods? I remember it was a nice plant. I want to keep the seeds, but I would like to know what kind of plant it is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the leaves of the plant look like? Can you get a photo of them?

Comment: I think all leaves disappeared - all what is left is on photos, but I am going to doublecheck. @Jurp

Comment: Gosh, I think this is a Rue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_chalepensis#/media/File:Ruta_chalepensis_Dried_fruits_Tigray_Region_Ethiopia.jpg

Comment: When you crush the leaves or debris, is there a strong earthy pungent smell?

Comment: Likely, Rose Campion. I love them too!

Answer (score 4):

It's a valvate capsule, possibly from some species of Hibiscus. I have helped collect Sorrel in the Caribbean for tea, very similar shape as this fruit but the sorrel is deeply red.

Answer (score 0):

the stalks look like a Lychnis coronaria,
but the seeds are big.

Agrostemma githago (corn-cockle) ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrostemma_githago
- http://www.inspection.gc.ca/vegetaux/semences/analyse-designation-de-categorie/identification-de-semences/agrostemma-githago/fra/1404825489475/1404825490522  (see pictures of seeds at bottom)

or Vaccaria ?